# How to make lambda for this function?

Tags: c++, lambda, g++

I am wondering how to make a lambda in C++ for this function and the type has to be void

```cpp
void setIO(string s){
   freopen((s+".in").c_str(),"r",stdin);
   freopen((s+".out").c_str(),"w",stdout);
}
```

Comment: What would be the point of doing so?

Comment: Something like that seems to be very common on so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites and their examples. You almost never need anything like that, in a function or a lambda or inline, anywhere. If you use such sites to learn anything, then you should consider that such sites are *not* any kind of learning or teaching resource, and using them as such could be actively harmfull to learning programming.

Comment: With that said, this question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to use such a function? Why do you need to turn it into a lambda? What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Those websites, when a user puts time into developing algorithmic knowledge, works to optimize the style of his code (by not creating low quality code just to pass or make it compact), and reads alternative submissions can be extremely useful to a programmer. There's a reason why Google's interview is basically only those questions. Additionally, it's a great sign when someone learns corners of a programming language for the sake of knowing everything in a logical manner. I can't believe you're suggesting that comprehending edge cases in a language's design is useless.

Comment: @user904963 I didn't say such sites are useless, for those who already know programming and a few languages. They are however harmful for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const string FILE_NAME = "test.txt";
    
    auto f = [](string const &name) -> void {
        ofstream file;
        file.open(name);
        file << "junk\n" << "junk2" << endl;;
        file.close();
    };
    
    f(FILE_NAME);
    
    ifstream inputFile(FILE_NAME);
    if (inputFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "File is open." << endl;
        string line;
        while (getline(inputFile, line))
            cout << line << '\n';
        cout << flush;
        inputFile.close();
    } else
        cerr << "Error opening file." << endl;
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, lambda functions can deduce the return type, so you can leave out `-> void`.

```
auto f = [](string const &name) {
        ofstream file;
        file.open(name);
        file << "junk\n" << "junk2" << endl;;
        file.close();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent way to create a lambda would be:

```
auto f = [](string s) -> void { 
        //freopen((s+".in").c_str(),"r",stdin);
        //freopen((s+".out").c_str(),"w",stdout);
        std::cout<<"inside lambda"<<std::endl;
        
        //some other code here
        
    };
```

Now you can use/call this as:

```
f("passing some string");
```